# How do I trim long text with three dots of Node in jstree?

Tags: jstree

When long text documents are uploaded then my popup's width gets altered.
Is there any way to trim long text with three dots for tree node's text?

Following is my HTML code to create tree structure

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="height:100%;overflow:auto" ng-if="IsTree">
            <oe-jstree source="AssemblyDocuments"
                       name="documenttree"
                       is-upload-file="true"
                       options="treeOptions"
                       tree-node-creator="createNode(item)"
                       on-item-selected="NodeSelected(item)"
                       on-item-created="NodeCreated(item, callback)"
                       on-item-renamed="NodeRenamed(item, callback)"
                       on-item-removed="NodeRemoved(item, callback)"
                       on-item-archived="NodeArcive(item, callback)"
                       on-item-download="onItemDownload(item, callback)"
                       on-item-tagged="onItemTagged(item, callback)"
                       tag-list="TagMst"
                       is-read-only="isReadOnly"
                       id="documenttree"></oe-jstree>
        </div>
```

[image]

How can I cut text and show three dots with a tooltip?

Comment: I want to do the same thing, did you work this out?

Comment: I have added an answer to your problem. Hope it would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.createNode = function (nodedata) {
        if (nodedata.Name != null)
            nodedata.Name = nodedata.Name.trim();

        var node = {
            id: nodedata.Id,
            text: nodedata.Name.substr(0, 60) + (nodedata.Name.length > 60 ? "..." : ""),
            state: {
                opened: true
            },
            type: nodedata.isFile == true ? File : Folder,
            icon: nodedata.isFile == true ? (nodedata.Archive == true ? 'jstree-zip' : 'jstree-file') : 'jstree-folder',
            children: GetChilders(nodedata),
            FileTagDetails: nodedata.FileTagDetails,
            model: nodedata,
            a_attr: {
                title: nodedata.Name
            }
        };
        return node;
    };
```

By using `text: nodedata.Name.substr(0, 60) + (nodedata.Name.length > 60 ? "..." : ""),` you can achieve 3 dots

Comment: thanks for taking the time to do this, much appreciated.